# In Corona SDK, how do I use the 'and' keyword in if, elseif, else statements?

Tags: android, ios, lua, cross-platform, coronasdk

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
if randomNumber <=10 then
    physics.setGravity( 20, 0 )

elseif randomNumber > 10 and <= 20 then

    physics.setGravity( -20, 0 )

elseif randomNumber > 20  and <= 30 then

    physics.setGravity( 0, 20 )
else 
    physics.setGravity( 0, -20 )
end
```

For some reason I get an error message when I try to run the program.  If anyone could help, that would be great.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The error message is:   Unexpected symbol near '<='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elseif randomNumber > 10 and randomNumber <= 20 then
```

The things on either side of the "and" or "or" have to evaluate to a true or false value.  Thus:

```
randomNumber > 10
```

is a valid comparison.  However:

```
<= 20
```

is not. What is less than or equal to 20?  Without specifying a variable/value on the left hand side, it has no idea what you are trying to see is less than or equal to 20.

Some times you will see:

```
if someValue or someOtherValue then
```

In that case, someValue and someOtherValue are evaluating to either true or false without having to compare it to another value.  When you specify just a single variable then what it's really asking is:

Is someValue not nil or is it not false.  Any other answer is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (randomNumber <=10) then
    physics.setGravity( 20, 0 )

elseif (randomNumber > 10) and (randomNumber <= 20) then

    physics.setGravity( -20, 0 )

elseif (randomNumber > 20) and (randomNumber <= 30 then

    physics.setGravity( 0, 20 )
else 
    physics.setGravity( 0, -20 )
end
```

Try this.